# Next.js Variables reset after i switch pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Im trying to simply have a shared variable between my pages in my Next.Js application.. My _app.js below contains the following..

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const CustomApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

  // Variables
  const [testVariable, setTestVariable] = useState(0)

  // globalFunctions
  const setTestVariable = (newValue) => setLocalVariable(newValue);


  return (
    <Component 
      {...pageProps}
      // Export Variables
      testVariable={testVariable}
      // Export Functions
      setTestVariable={setTestVariable}

    />
  );
}

export default CustomApp
```

I have two pages... Both are the same except one is called index.js and exports Home, the other is called about.js and exports About...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const Home = ({ testVariable, setTestVariable, }) => {

 
  useEffect(() => {

  })

  
  return (
    <div id={styles.outerDiv}>
      <Head>
        <title>My Next.Js Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Next.js application" />
      </Head>

      <div id={styles.navBar}>
        <a href="/" id={styles.navLink}>
          <h3>Home</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="/about.js" id={styles.navLink}>
          <h3>About</h3>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id={styles.content} className="content">
        <br/>
        <h2>Test Variable: {testVariable}</h2>

        <button id={styles.incrementButton} onClick={setTestVariable(1)}>Set Test Variable to 1</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

When I tap the button the variable on my page changes to 1, however when I switch pages the variable goes back to 0. I also receive no errors of any sort. All feedback is greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable goes back to 0 because you are using `a` tags wich "reloads" the page
To navigate you should use the `Link` component that is built in next.

This `Link` component prevents the default behavior of reload the page and you can keep your state while navigate on the page